# Local network - multiple internet access

Tags: networking, router, internet

[image: Sample image]

I have 3 routers each one have different internet access than the others.
from the sample image I posted. I named the Routers with R1 R2 and R3

I'm currently using 2 different internet access on separate networks.
R1- using subnet address 192.168.1.1 
and R2 using subnet address 192.168.0.1
what I want to do is to connect the R3 to R2 and access it's internet from my pc.
is this a valid configuration ?
How can I do that exactly ?

Comment: Try bridging R2 to R3

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. However I've assumed that you want to send all traffic via R3 - if R3 is dead then R2 will start using Internet 2 - but otherwise it will only use R3

I R3 and its connection to R2 is brand new

So setup R3 up with a default gateway pointing to the ISP provider of Internet 3

On R3 you need add a second interface and give it an address 192.168.3.1/24

On R2 you add a new interface and give it an address 192.168.3.2/24
Connect these together

On R2 add a route  to the internet (or just the addresses you wish to reach using "Internet 3")  with the gateway being 192.168.3.1

On R3 you need to add a route to 192.168.0.1/24  via 192.168.3.2

If however you only want the PC to go via R3/Internet 3 and there are other devices - R2 will need to decide based on the source address so you will need to classify the traffic using ACLs or something else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a valid configuration.

(assuming the netmask for the other LAN segments is 255.255.255.0 [/24] ) Configure R3 to 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 AND ENSURE THAT DHCP IS TURNED OFF.

Connect a LAN port from R3 to R2, so that your PC, R2 and R3 are all on the same segment.  When you want to use R2 use DHCP on your computer (or its static IP config).  When you want to use R2 change to a static IP address configuration specifying an IP address in 192.168.2.x netmask 255.255.255.0, and a gateway of 192.168.2.1

There are other ways of doing this using VLANS etc, but they are probably needlessly complex and may not work with simpler routers.

Comment: I tried your configuration but got some issues. I cannot see the other routers that are on different network than the gateway. when I set static IP on my pc for 192.168.0.x I cannot see or access the router 192.168.2.1 -  but when I set both of them on same network R3 + R2 on 192.168.0.x network it worked for me (to some extent)  I just had to specify which default gateway my network adapter should use to access the different internet.